# GPL modify code

Tags: gpl

If I take GPL code  and modify it, does it have to still be under GPL?

Comment: Yes, but only if you distribute it.

Comment: You can ask the original copyright holder to relicense it to you. If she agrees...

Comment: I am the original copyright holder. Can I relicense myself?

Comment: Of course! If you're the original copyright holder you're not bound by the GPL: the GPL is a license for others to distribute your code. You're free to do wherever you chose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yes, it does](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html).

> You may convey a work based on the
>   Program, or the modifications to
>   produce it from the Program, in the
>   form of source code under the terms of
>   section 4, provided that you also meet
>   all of these conditions:
>
> 1. The work must carry prominent notices stating that you modified it,
>      and giving a relevant date.
> 2. The work must carry prominent notices stating that it is released
>      under this License and any conditions
>      added under section 7. This
>      requirement modifies the requirement
>      in section 4 to “keep intact all
>      notices”.
> 3. **You must license the entire work, as a whole, under this License
>      to anyone who comes into possession of
>      a copy. This License will therefore
>      apply, along with any applicable
>      section 7 additional terms, to the
>      whole of the work, and all its parts,
>      regardless of how they are packaged.**
>      This License gives no permission to
>      license the work in any other way, but
>      it does not invalidate such permission
>      if you have separately received it.
> 4. If the work has interactive user interfaces, each must display
>      Appropriate Legal Notices; however, if
>      the Program has interactive interfaces
>      that do not display Appropriate Legal
>      Notices, your work need not make them
>      do so.
>
> A compilation of a covered work with
>   other separate and independent works,
>   which are not by their nature
>   extensions of the covered work, and
>   which are not combined with it such as
>   to form a larger program, in or on a
>   volume of a storage or distribution
>   medium, is called an “aggregate” if
>   the compilation and its resulting
>   copyright are not used to limit the
>   access or legal rights of the
>   compilation's users beyond what the
>   individual works permit. Inclusion of
>   a covered work in an aggregate does
>   not cause this License to apply to the
>   other parts of the aggregate.

If you don't distribute it, however, this does not apply.

Answer (score 1):

If you own the copyright for the work in question, you can license it in any way you want. In fact, you can have [more than one license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-licensing) for the same work. If you do not own the copyright, you are bound by the terms of the license. SLaks provides a good overview of what that means.